# Define Initial condition for matlab function blocks as an Initial condition in sfunction block

Tags: matlab

I have defined  `'my sys'`in matlab `s-function`space as below:

```
    ....
            sys = simsizes(s);


        case 1  % derivative

                sys = mysys(t,x,u,opts);


        case 3  % output

            sys = x ;
.....
```

and I put initial condition `(dx0)` of system states in s-function parameters space.[S-function parameters block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdCtz.png)

Now I have defined `my sys` in a `matlab function block` but there is nothing like s-function block to put my initial `(dx0)` condition in it.
[sys in matlab function block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oylHz.png)

I'm interested to know how can I define `dx0` for matlab function block?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be confusing three things.

1. The first thing is the MATLAB code you're posting which I'm not sure is supposed to go where exactly.
2. The second thing is the first picture you're linking. That indeed shows the dialog box of an S-function, which requires you to provide a .c file (in the C language) for the code. Perhaps you were intending to use a Level 2 S-function, where you can enter MATLAB code.
3. The third thing is the second picture you're linking. That one shows an embedded MATLAB function, which is not the same as a Level 2 S-function, which explains why you don't see a dialog box where you can enter a parameter.

What you're trying to do (I guess) is to calculate derivatives using some function, i.e., xdot = f(x). You can do that using either:
- an embedded MATLAB function
- an S-function
- a Level 2 S-function
All of these can set an initial condition as well. However, you probably want to integrate the derivatives. In that case you'd want to set the initial condition on an integrator block that you're adding after your function block.