# How to define Initial condition for matlab function block

Tags: matlab

How can I define initial conditions for Eq of motion states I defined in matlab function block?
I want to be able to define my initial conditions as part of the function block definition that system can use it to run . Something like a question asked in link:

[Define Initial condition for matlab function blocks as an Initial condition in sfunction block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33652063/define-initial-condition-for-matlab-function-blocks-as-an-initial-condition-in-s)

I put some part of my codes:

```
   % desription of system with baseline conroller(bac)
function Smc_sig = sys (X,d_AIL,d_RUD,d_STAB,aij_cef,landa_states,Q_qoef,States_derivatives_trims,T)

.
.
.
%==========================================================================
% State ordering 


V       =  X(1);       % Airspeed , ft/s
beta    =  X(2);       % Sideslip Angle, rad
alpha   =  X(3);       % Angle-of-attack, rad

p       =  X(4);       % Roll rate, rad/s
q       =  X(5);       % Pitch rate, rad/s
r       =  X(6);       % Yaw rate, rad/s

phi     =  X(7);       % Roll Angle, rad
theta   =  X(8);       % Pitch Angle, rad
psi     =  X(9);       % Yaw Angle, rad

.
.
.
Smc_sig = [...];
```

I want define initial condition for states x(1) ...x(9) and system use these initial condition to start simulink in a loop.If not I counter error.My system is in a loop and uses the initial conditions related to these states.

Comment: Not sure that I am following what you mean by "initial conditions". Do you want define a set of static values that are used as starting points for your equations? Or do you want to be able to define your initial conditions as part of the function block definition? Something else? Consider adding a bit more detail to your question so that it will be easier to understand.

Comment: What kind of function block are you talking about? S-function? Embedded MATLAB function? Equations of Motion block from the Aerospace blockset?

Comment: I used User defined matlab function

Comment: The question you linked to is no clearer than yours. Can you show us some code that will give us an idea of what you want, even if it doesn't work properly?

Comment: The easiest way to do what you want is make `V, beta, alpha, p, q, r, phi, theta, and psi` inputs.  Then set their values with an initial condition block.  If you need to use them during each loop make them feedback with the `IC` block in the loop.  It will only affect the first loop.

Comment: Could you please explain more about initial condition block.

Comment: Where is it and how does it work?